# Is there a driver for Nvidia Titan Xp GPU for ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, gpu, gpu-driver

I have a Titan Xp collector's edition. Since I wasn't able to find a driver on nvidia's website for Titan Xp on Ubuntu, I didn't install any driver. But now my computer screen freezes randomly sometimes and I suspect it's caused by lack of driver.

When the screen freezes, it freezes for about 10 seconds and it goes no-signal, at which point the led on my graphics card starts to blink periodically.

Has anyone experienced this before?

EDIT:
one of the answers says to use the 384 driver. However that driver doesn't work for CUDA with linux 4.13 kernel. see https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1028904/nvidia-driver-not-loading-after-cuda-9-1-installation-with-runfile/#5234072
So I installed 390.12 as suggested in that post but I still occasionally encounter these freezes.

Right now I just want to know if this seems like a graphics card driver issue or did I not install Ubuntu correctly? Or is this a problem with firefox? Since everytime it seems to freeze when I'm using firefox (though I don't have that many samples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 64-bit Linux Nvidia recommends

> Version:  384.111
> Release Date:     2018.1.4
> Operating System:     Linux 64-bit
> Language:     English (US)
> File Size:    77.25 MB
>
> **Supported products**
>
> **NVIDIA TITAN Series:**
>
> NVIDIA TITAN Xp, NVIDIA TITAN X (Pascal), GeForce GTX TITAN X, GeForce
> GTX TITAN, GeForce GTX TITAN Black, GeForce GTX TITAN Z

See: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/128737/en-us

So you may start with installing `nvidia-384` package
from `software-properties-gtk` (*Software & Updates*)

Answer (score 1):

Driver version Version: **390.42** is now available for X86_64 linux see below link:

- Version: 390.42
- Release Date:    2018.3.12
- Operating System:    Linux 64-bit
- Language:    English (US)
- File Size:   78.05 MB

http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/131853/en-us